# How to read RPGLE source code into a variable in another program

Tags: rpgle

How can I read RPG source code into a variable in another RPG program? This is so I can analyze the code to edit it.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Do you  want to open the source code of a program?  Or execute it? Or debug to see your variable content?

Comment: I want to put the source code of a program into 1 variable or read lines for edit it from my new program

Answer (score 1):

If your source member is in a FILE/MEMBER you can open and read it with SQL. You have to use an alias because SQL can't directly select from a multi-member file.

```
CREATE ALIAS lib/youralias FOR lib/filesource (sourcemember);
```

use a SQLRPGLE with a cursor to read line by line :

```
SELECT * FROM lib/youralias;
```

If your source is in the IFS, you can also read it with SQL + cursor :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(QSYS2.IFS_READ('/home/dir/yoursource.rpg'))
```

Comment: If you don't want to use an alias, you could also use a file override to select a member.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use SQL, you can also read a source file like any other database file in RPG. To read a specific member, you can use an override, or you can use the EXTMBR() keyword on the F spec.

Here is a link to the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=keywords-extmbrmembername)